# Tensorflow: TypeError: get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_metrics_per_category'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_300x300_coco14 on CoLab.

Here is the command:

```
!python /root/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
--pipeline_config_path=/drive/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_300x300_coco14_sync.config \
--model_dir=/drive/data/ \
--num_train_steps=50000 \
--num_eval_steps=2000 \
--alsologtostderr
```

... and the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 101, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 97, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 451, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 590, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 691, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 376, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1145, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1173, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1451, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 583, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1059, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1150, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1135, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1215, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 464, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 489, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 497, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 517, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 884, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 463, in evaluate
    input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1463, in _evaluate_build_graph
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/root/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 387, in model_fn
    include_metrics_per_category=eval_config.include_metrics_per_category)
TypeError: get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_metrics_per_category'
```

Does anybody know how to get rid the error?

**TypeError: get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_metrics_per_category'**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by switching to Python 2 in Runtime settings.

But still don't know how to fix it on Python 3 :|